# Joining a table with itself vs using Group By MySQL

Tags: mysql

Here is a simplified version of my table:

It contains the columns
`employee_id  column2  column3   x   y`
and they are all `NUMERIC`

I am having trouble writing a complicated MySQL query. I want to get all the `employeeid` and `column3` values for all employees that have the same value in `column2` as another employee and have DIFFERENT values for `x` and `y` PAIR from every other employee. For example, if the following 4 rows were in table:

```
2 100 123.456 5 7
1 234 123.456 5 7
3 100 456.789 5 10
4 100 123.456 5 7
```

The rows `2 100 123.456 5 7` and `3 100 456.789 5 10` should be obtained because they have different employee ids (`2` vs `3`), the same value for `column2` (`100` and `100`), and different `x`, `y` pair: (Employee 2 has `x` = 5 and `y` = 7, which is distinct from `x` = 5 and `y` = 10).

How can I compare the documents of table with other documents within itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e1.*
FROM employee e1
JOIN employee e2
  ON e1.employee_id <> e2.employee_id  
 AND e1.column2 = e2.column2 
 AND e1.X <> e2.X
 AND e1.Y <> e2.Y
```

But I guess your last condition should be

```
AND (e1.X <> e2.X OR e1.Y <> e2.Y)
```

Comment: hmm I'm not getting the answer I expect but this answer does seem right for the problem I mentioned in my OP